# How to escape a string so it does not get replaced by Token::replace()

Tags: 8, tokens

I have a string that is being sent into the replace method of the token service that looks like a token, but it is not.

Here is an example of the string: "['key:value']"

Is it possible to escape this in a way that the replace function will not think it is a token that it needs to replace?

The "clear" flag in the replace function is set to true, so this string always just gets removed, but I want it to ignore this string entirely. Thanks!

Comment: Try &#91;key&#58;value&#93;

Answer (score 0):

[`Token::replace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21Token.php/function/Token%3A%3Areplace/8.2.x) allows you to use a callback to replace extra tokens no module define, but that is called after the tokens have been replaced; plus, it gets a array as `array($original_token => $replacement)` which makes things slower since you would need to replace each token one by one.

I would rather set `'clear'` to `FALSE`, and then replace all the tokens that have not been replaced with an empty string. Since the strings you need to keep follow a specific pattern, it would be easier to remove the unreplaced tokens with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).